# Can someone explain output of this program?

Tags: c

The output of this program is:

> XBCDO
>   HELLE

Can someone explain why this is so?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(char **p, char **q) {
    char *temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    char a[10] = "HELLO";
    char  b[10] = "XBCDE";
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("%s %s", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Actually it compiles (gcc 5.4.0)
I have the following output XBCDE HELLO

Comment: @mch it compiles in c. not in c++

Comment: The Program does compile. But gives two warnings though. The output is `XBCDE HELLO`.

Comment: @mch it compiles on gcc 4.9.2. I tested.

Comment: The final character not swapping, might this be an array index first value found at 0 not 1 issue? Guessing, I can't see myself the true cause....

Comment: @Zermingore: You seem to have ignored the warnings about implicit pointer conversion or use some ancient C version.

Comment: @anacron I can reproduce the OP's claimed behavior if I compile their program with 32-bit pointers.  The program has undefined behavior, and the concrete thing that is happening is, `swap` is swapping the first (number of bytes in a `char *`) in the *contents of the arrays*.  With 32-bit pointers, that's the first four letters in each string; with 64-bit, that appears to be the entire string because the strings are short, but really it's just the first eight bytes.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't say it's safe or warning-free, just said it compiles (with gcc 5.4.0) as mch said it doesn't compile

Comment: @Olaf for sure this is not a good practice. However, the code compiles and the OP asked why it prints first XBCDO

Comment: @Zermingore: Just that it compiles does not mean it is correct. If you are serious about warnings, you treat them as errors (which they should in general). Many companies and semi-pros have a strict policy of requiring `-Werror`.

Comment: @granmirupa: see above. A lot of problematic code a C compiler is allowed to pass without diagnostics would generate an error in strictily typed languages (which C is not).

Comment: @zwol That's interesting. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused about the difference between pointers and arrays.  (It *is* a confusing part of the language.)  `swap` expects pointers to pointers, but you have given it pointers to *arrays*.  This is such a serious mistake that GCC warns about it even if you don't turn on any warnings (it *ought* to issue hard errors, but some very, very old code does stuff like this intentionally and they don't want to break that).

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&a, &b);
          ^
test.c:3:1: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
 swap(char **p, char **q)
 ^~~~
test.c:16:14: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&a, &b);
              ^
test.c:3:1: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
 swap(char **p, char **q)
 ^~~~
```

The mistake causes the program to have *undefined behavior* - it doesn't have to do anything that makes any sense at all.

The program you probably were trying to write looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void swap(char **p, char **q)
{
    char *temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[10] = "HELLO";
    char b[10] = "XBCDE";
    char *c = a;
    char *d = b;
    swap(&c, &d);
    printf("%s %s", c, d);
}
```

The output of this program is `XBCDE HELLO`, which I think is what you were expecting.  `c` and `d` are actually pointers, and they are set to point to the first elements of the arrays `a` and `b`; `swap` works as expected when applied to `c` and `d`.

If it doesn't make any sense that `c` and `d` are different from `a` and `b`, you need to get your hands on a good C textbook and you need to read the chapter on pointers and do all the exercises.  (If it doesn't have at least one entire chapter on pointers, with exercises, it's not a good C textbook.)

Comment: You should add your comment on the question to this answer.

Comment: can u pls suggest from where i can read array vs pointer ....i have been confused with this for very long...

Comment: @AnkushDwivedi Go to your local public library and ask for a C textbook.